# What's the best way to declare a new thread via an anonymous class?

Tags: java, constructor, inner-classes, java-threads, anonymous-class

I've been checking some technical stuff about Threads in Java and I'm a little bit confused about a specific issue when I define a thread with an anonymous class (proper use of parenthesis in the constructor definition).
The regular declaration would be this one:

```
    Thread myRunnableThread3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("myRunnableThread3!");
        }
    });
    myRunnableThread3.start();
```

And just for experimentation purposes, I tried this:

```
    Thread myRunnableThread3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable()){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("myRunnableThread3!");
        }
    };
    myRunnableThread3.start();
```

As you may see, both look pretty similar and the output console it's the same.
So, Am I missing something? maybe there is a little slightly functional difference that I'm not realizing yet. By the way, I'm using Java Corretto 11.
Both look OK, maybe should I go for the first option?
Thanks for your comments and help.

Comment: they are different as they create an anonymous class of different things: `MyRunnable` and `Thread`. Neither is OK, if you ask me. It is a lot simpler to just `Thread myRunnableThread3 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("myRunnableThread3!"))`

Comment: "*What's the best way*" questions are usually opinion-based, and hence, [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

The first is creating an anonymous subclass of `MyRunnable`.

The second is creating an anonymous subclass of `Thread`, which requires that `MyRunnable` is instantiable; and `MyRunnable` wouldn't actually then be used at all, because it's not invoked in the `run()` method you're defining in the `Thread` subclass.

There is no reason to subclass `Thread`, and presumably you want some special behavior from your `MyRunnable` base class (although the only thing that would provide special behavior that would actually be run is the constructor).

Use the first way.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I didn't realize that specific detail. Even when they look pretty similar (at least for a newbie like me), the parenthesis isolates the constructor and the class declaration body. Thanks!
Eventually, I will master lambda expressions, and functional interfaces will help me a lot with this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a lambda expression to start a thread.

```
Thread myRunnableThread3 = new Thread(()-> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("myRunnableThread3!");},"MyThread");

    
myRunnableThread3.start();
```

Prints

```
MyThread
myRunnableThread3!
```